# How to export files in background using Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using Yii2 framework and I have a huge table which could have more than 1 million rows and that I should export into a Excel file.
The problem is that this operation could take even more than 10 minutes, blocking the user navigation in the Web App.
I would like to do this export operation in background, so the user can continue navigating the web app and then he receive a notification when the export is completed and he can download the result.

I searched online but I only found this guide:
https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/840/background-task-with-ajax

But it refers to and old version of the framework (Yii 1.0) and doesn't work with Yii2.

Could this guide help me with what I'm trying to do?

These are my files, which I'm trying to make working in Yii2:

**runtask.php:**

```
<script>

    function test() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                par: document.getElementById("par").value
            },
            success: function() {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function(exception) {
                alert(exception);
            }
        });
    }
</script>


<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['runtask'],
    'id' => 'runTask-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'method' => 'post',
]);
?>

<label for="par">Parameter</label>

<input type="text" name="par" id="par">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-button" onclick="test()">Submit</button>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

<div id="output"></div>

<?php
// Link to download the result
if ($lt && $lt->cont || ($par && $lt)) {
    echo "Result " . $par . ": ";
    echo Html::a(
        Html::encode($lt->filename),
        array('longtask/download', 'id' => $lt->id)
    );
}
```

**Controller.php**

```
    // The action runTask
    public function actionRuntask()
    {

        $model = new Example; // the model to generate report
        $par = ''; // form parameter

        // Returned from the form
        if (isset($_POST['par'])) {
            $par = $_POST['par']; // parameter specified
            $fn = "FILE_$par.txt"; // file name
            $mime = 'text/plain'; // file type
            $cont = $model->doTask($par); // long report generation

            // Ajax button
            $request = Yii::$app->request;
            if ($request->isAjax) { //returns false, but I don't know why
                $lt = new Longtask;
                $lt->cleanMy(); // deletes the previous task result
                $lt->filename = $fn;
                $lt->cont = $cont;
                $lt->mime = $mime;
                $lt->save(); // creates new task record
                Yii::$app->end(); // end of Ajax initiated process
            }

            // Normal submit button: download file
            else {
                Yii::$app->response->sendFile($fn, $cont, $mime);
            }
        }

        // Calls the form
        $lt = Longtask::find()->where(['task' => Yii::$app->request->url, 'username' => Yii::$app->user->identity->username])->one();

        // last task
        $this->render('runtask', ['par' => $par, 'lt' => $lt]);
    }
```

Comment: Create a console command and run this from CLI or as a cronjob.

Comment: Be aware that 1,048,576 is the maximum limit of rows in a worksheet in excel: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#ID0EDBD=Newer_versions

Comment: How could I pass the entire table as input of the console command so it can generate the file?

Comment: Using ajax to run time consuming task in background is not a best option. You would have to deal with fact, that AJAX request can be aborted because of timeout, navigation or network error. There is [`yii2-queue`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-queue) extension designed to run tasks in background.